# When animating view with UIView.animate other views are also needlessly animated

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I'm wondering why views in my custom TableViewCells are affected by animation which should animate only 2 views in my floating pager (which is even not in TableView's view hierarchy..

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    self.stateIndicator.isHiddenInStackView = true
    self.loaderIndicator.isHiddenInStackView = false
}
```

When I comment out animation block everything stops animating.

Attached GIF describes everything (Blue views gets animated corner radius, badges 'flies in' instead of just appearing):

UIView.animate strange behavior

[image]

Any help or hint will be appreciated :).

Regards Tom.

Comment: What is `isHiddenInStackView`? Is this property's setter doing something?

Comment: It's only "safe-hide-unhide"

var isHiddenInStackView: Bool {
    get {
      return isHidden
    }
    set {
      if isHidden != newValue {
        isHidden = newValue
      }
    }
  }
"The bug is that hiding and showing views in a stack view is cumulative. Weird Apple bug."
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45599835/9413528

Comment: I don’t think that bug is relevant. It just says that you’re have to set `isHidden` multiple times to have an affect.

Comment: My guess would be that since your pager is getting data about the table view, it might be triggering a table view reload somehow. If that table reload is triggered indirectly by the pager, then it’s changes might get caught by the animation block.

Comment: @ABeard89 I'm updating the pager after table view gets more data from background thread. So pager do nothing with table view at all.

Comment: can you share the code below these lines `UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    self.stateIndicator.isHiddenInStackView = true
    self.loaderIndicator.isHiddenInStackView = false
}`

Comment: @ABeard89 you were 100% right! I had to move pager initialization code to viewDidAppear (from viewWillAppear) and it worked without wrapping things into UIView.performWithoutAnimation {}. Animation block was the issue here, somehow. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I’m glad the timing fixed the issue! (`performWithoutAnimation` seems like a hack to me.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the things which you don't want to animate in the block

```
  UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
     //Write your code here
  }
```

Comment: It worked, but I still dont understand why it happens? Now I have to use   performWithoutAnimation in many places..

Comment: sometimes happen, suppose you are animating something and before committing that animation another UI operation is started that will be automatically animated due to that animation block

Comment: Thank you for help, I will stay with it.

Answer (score 0):

I make my animation in main queue and it worked.
For example

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     //Write animation code here
}
```